# WPF Border element background animation

Tags: border

I want to animate the background of a border when the mouse is enters and leaves.

Here is my code

```xaml
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#6990EE90" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:3" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

...

    <ListBox Height="158" Name="lstStats" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationStatsValues}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Name="lulu" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.8" BorderBrush="LightGreen" CornerRadius="3" Margin="0,0,0,2">
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush />
                </Border.Background>
                <DockPanel Height="60" Width="284" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Description}" Height="30" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Title}" Height="30" Width="220" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding Value}" Height="30" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The problem is that i always get this error :

**'Background' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(Background).(0)'.**

This works perfectly with `<Style Targetype="ListBoxItem">` but I don't want the background of the list item to change, it looks ugly. I want the border background to change because of the round border.

So the question is : how those DependencyObject works and how can i determine which one is the correct one for a given object, and can anyone make this works ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found a solution to make it work by putting the triggers inside the ItemTemplate itself.

Any explanation why it cannot work by targetting the type with an external style would be very welcome.

```xaml
    <ListBox Height="158" Name="lstStats" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationStatsValues}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.8" BorderBrush="LightGreen" CornerRadius="3" Margin="0,0,0,2">
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush />
                </Border.Background>
                <Border.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#6990EE90" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Border.Triggers>

                    <DockPanel Height="60" Width="284" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Description}" Height="30" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Title}" Height="30" Width="220" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding Value}" Height="30" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```